# Atom if I add to much snippets they does not appear

Tags: atom-editor

I have a quite stupid problem. I have added new snippets to snippets.cson file in atom, when I had 7 snippets they have worked but now when I added 'Laravel validator' snippet the **laravel validator** snippet does not work **but other snippets work**.
Here's my snippets:

```
# PHP LARAVEL
'.source.php':
  'Normal Comment Block':
    'prefix': 'cmm'
    'body': """
      //**********************************************************************************
      // $1
      //**********************************************************************************
      $0
    """
  'Public function with request':
    'prefix': 'funreq'
    'body': """
      public function $1 (Request $request) {

      }
      $0
    """
  'Public function':
    'prefix': 'fun'
    'body': """
      public function $1 () {

      }
      $0
    """
    'Laravel validator':
        'prefix': 'thisvalidate'
        'body': """
          $this->validate($request, [
            '$1' => '$request['']',
            ]);
    """
# PHP JS
'.source.js':
  'Normal Comment Block':
    'prefix': 'cmm'
    'body': """
      //**********************************************************************************
      // $1
      //**********************************************************************************
      $0
    """
  'Font color red':
    'prefix': 'fontcolorred'
    'body': """
      <font color="red">$1</font>
    """
  'Ajax with done function':
    'prefix': 'ajaxwithdone'
    'body': """
      $.ajax({
        method:"post",
        url:url,
        data:{}
        }).done(function(msg) {

        });
    """
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `thisvalidate` snippet doesn't work for two reasons:

1. The `source.php` scope requires PHP opening and closing tags, outside of these your snippet cannot be triggered. Keep in mind, that in Atom there are multiple scopes for PHP, see this [forum post](https://discuss.atom.io/t/php-snippets-not-working/15321/8?u=idleberg) for details.
2. Wrong CSON indentation

Comment: Thanks, it was all about indentation!